# Detect if user used pasteboard (OTP one time password) or did it manually

Tags: ios, swift, passwords, boolean

How to check if User pasted or not

```
private(set) lazy var code: BehaviorRelay<String> = .init(value: .empty)
    let dtoRequest: CAuthByOTPDtoRequest = .init(phone: dto.phone,
                                                 state: dto.timeout?.state,
                                                 code: code.value)

    if dtoRequest.code!.contains(UIPasteboard.general.string ?? "") {
        debugPrint("Pasted")
    } else {
        debugPrint("Not Pasted")
    }
```

I tried this solution, but it wrong

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if string.count == 6 {
        //Pasted
        //or string.count > 1, cause user cannot input more than 1 character a time
    } else {
        //Not Pasted
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I tried this solution, and it doesn't work

Comment: But if user will did it manually, it also will be string.count == 6

Comment: user cannot input more than 1 number a time, user input manually must be string.count == 1, check the param 'replacementString string'

Comment: how make it without using "replacementString string", because I'm using this condition in vm, and can't use textField function directly.

Comment: You can use key-value to set the delegate `textField.setValue(self, forKey: "delegate")`, and change the param type of the function `func textField(_ textField: AnyObject ...`

Comment: or, you can add a notification observer `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(textChanged), name: UITextField.textDidChangeNotification, object: nil)`, create a funtion `func textChanged`, it will be called if the text changed. (if u canot use UITextField.textDidChangeNotification, u can use `Notification.Name.init("UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification")` instead)

Answer (score 0):

This workaround working for me

1. create two private var

```swift
 private var oneTimeCode: String = ""
 private var oneTimeCodeTimer: Timer?`
```

2. add this logic in delegate method

```swift
 public func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        let currentString: NSString = (textField.text ?? "") as NSString
        let newString = currentString.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)      
 
        oneTimeCodeTimer?.invalidate()
        oneTimeCode = oneTimeCode + string
        oneTimeCodeTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: false) { [weak self] _ in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            // 2 - because impossible tap 3 times in a row, 0.1 seconds for one tap
            if self.oneTimeCode.count > 2  {
    
              // **Do something with newString**
              //code did paste
}
            self.oneTimeCode = ""
        }
        
        return true
    }
```